# fresh install drupal using drush

Tags: drush

I get an access denied on the front page with a fresh install using drush. I can get to the user page fine and login as admin. I read that it might be permissions. Not sure why be default its set like this though. Any thoughts?

Update:

Let me clarify what I need to understand. So previous deployments of drupal using drush I get a fully working site with permissions set correctly. Now I am not sure what is going on wrong but when I run

```
drush si standard (database info)
```

I get a freshly installed site with no permissions on the front page. Now I guess what I am trying to understand what is causing this using drush. From what I know and experienced drush si should install the site to a state in which drupal has permissions of anonymous set correct.

I can manipulate the database after deployment but I'd rather not do that if I can make it work with drush right away.

So what could be causing this issue? Am I using drush incorrectly when deploying it?

update:
I think it was a timing issue between mysql and drupal. In any case this is solved.

Comment: Is this a database access denied or webserver access denied?

Comment: It is a "access denied" on the front page of drupal with a "You are not authorized to access this page." I get the drupal theme with it so it doesnt seem to be a apache thing. I can access mysite.com/user just fine and login then I can see the content. But as an anonymous user i get the access denied.

Comment: I'd check the permissions for content to make sure the content type is accessible for anonymous users

Comment: My scenario is that this deployment has to be automated so with drush in theory it should have been accessible but not sure why its not working. I could go into the db and manipulate the permissions but if possible id like to have install correctly to begin with. Is there a reason everytime I do a new install of this I get the  access denied?

Comment: I believe if you have content and your permissions are set properly in database your deployment run as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be your content permissions are not configured.

Go in your admin,  people->permissions->node and look in the "View published Content" permission, make sure anonymous and authenticated user is checked.

Comment: So do you know why that happens when running a drush si standard? it almost seems like this might be a minimal install but since I haven't done a minimal install before I am not sure if this is the case. Now it works for anonymous users but it says no front page created. When I used drush before the default front page has a login and content. Do you know why in my case it differs?

Comment: I don't think there is any content on a new install, though I am not 100% certain. Please accept & upvote the answer if it solved your issue so others can benefit it they encounter the same problem.  Thnaks friend.

Comment: This is a fix but doesn't really help me in my situation and its my fault for not writing this question properly.